# Replace multiple strings in xml file (batch)

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, sed

I want to create a batch program that finds and replaces strings in xml file.

Example:

```
a39c82f341ba4c5aaa9b6536 to VT4,1_0,0_KAL-ZG_2,2m
0518ffb000d6415dbaaa1b97 to VT4,1+2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m
331025a98e844fe8bbc52785 to VT4,1-2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m
```

I coded and I created this using gnu sed:

```
SET SED_PATH=SED.EXE -i
%SED_PATH% "s/54d73c26be75470f8d5d337d/VT4,1-2,5_KAL-ZG_3,3m/g" "s/1688215fce1142d488c1097b/jtr_stred_zapad/g" %filename%
```

But it doesn't detect if some string in file exists and it gives an error.

Comment: or someone can post a code in vb.net i know it too

Answer (score 0):

if your file is not too big you can use [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "c:\some.xml" "a39c82f341ba4c5aaa9b6536" "VT4,1_0,0_KAL-ZG_2,2m" "0518ffb000d6415dbaaa1b97" "VT4,1+2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m" "331025a98e844fe8bbc52785" "VT4,1-2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m"
```

more powerful solutions are [JREPL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) and [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Batch-JScript hybrid script that is very simple, but also very efficient; it will run on any Windows version from XP on. Save it with .bat extension.

```
@set @Batch=1 /*

@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < input.xml > output.xml
REM move /Y output.xml input.xml

goto :EOF    */

// JScript section

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace
   ( /(a39c82f341ba4c5aaa9b6536)|(0518ffb000d6415dbaaa1b97)|(331025a98e844fe8bbc52785)/g,
     function($0,$1,$2){return($1?"VT4,1_0,0_KAL-ZG_2,2m":$2?"VT4,1+2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m":"VT4,1-2,5_KAL-ZG_2,2m")} )
);
```

You may consult [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx) for a further description of regular expressions in JScript.